# TypeError: Undefined is not a function in simple if statement

Tags: javascript

I am getting frustrated with a simple `if` statement. I am getting an error

> TypeError: Undefined is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

```
  if (typeof lCost !== "undefined")
     totalExpenses = +totalExpenses + +lCost.isFixed(2);
```

Comment: Probably because lCost does not have a `isFixed` method, try a `console.log(lCost.isFixed)`.

Comment: remove quotes from undefined..

Comment: @Hawk Wrong advice. `typeof` returns a string.

Comment: (@Hawk what??) Error messages are generally constructed to provide useful information. Pay attention to them. It's telling you that you're trying to use something as a function, but it's *not* a function. There's only one attempt at a function call in that statement, so that must be the place to look for a problem.

Comment: @Satpal Most probably he wants to cast resulting string to a number, so your solution is invalid. Another thing is that the method `isFixed` must be a typo and should be replaced with `toFixed`.

Comment: Maybe you mean [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if( typeof lCost !== "undefined" )
{
totalExpenses  = +totalExpenses + +lCost.toFixed(2);
}
```

if I am not wrong, isFixed is not a built in function

Comment: `typeof` returns string, so you should quote `undefined`.

Comment: typeof does return a string. And does not return an undefined value for anything. So it really should have quotes.

Comment: I didn't get much sleep last night. Wow. isFixed? :)